# How to fix these XML errors?

Tags: xml, dtd

I'm learning how to program in XML and while doing an exercise I have encountered errors that I don't know how to deal with. 
Thanks in advance for those that will help me.

filmographie.dtd

```
<!ELEMENT films (film)+>
<!ELEMENT film (titre, visa, nationalite, pays, genres, exploitation,       
realisateur, duree, acteurs, scenario)>
<!ELEMENT titre (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT visa (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT nationalite (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT pays (nom)*>
<!ELEMENT nom (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT genres (genre)+>
<!ELEMENT genre (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT exploitation (date_de_sortie, nombre_entrees, nombre_salles)>
<!ELEMENT date_de_sortie (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT nombre_entrees (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT nombre_salles (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT realisateur (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT duree (heures, minutes)>
<!ELEMENT heures (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT minutes (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT acteurs (acteur+)>
<!ELEMENT acteur (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST heures unite CDATA 'h'>
<!ATTLIST minutes unite CDATA 'mn' >
<!ELEMENT scenario (#PCDATA) >
```

filmographie.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE filmographie SYSTEM "filmographie.dtd" >
<films>
    <film>
        <titre>King Kong</titre>
        <visa>114089</visa>
        <nationalite>Americain</nationalite>
        <pays>
            <nom>France</nom>
        </pays>
        <genres>
            <genre></genre>
        </genres>
        <exploitation>
            <date_de_sortie>2005_12_14</date_de_sortie>
            <nombre_entrees>2838759</nombre_entrees>
            <nombre_salles>547</nombre_salles>
        </exploitation>
        <realisateur>Peter Jackson</realisateur>
        <duree>
            <heures unite="h">3</heures>
            <minutes unite="mn">8</minutes>
        </duree>
        <acteurs> 
            <acteur>Peter Jackson</acteur>
            <acteur>Naomi Watts</acteur>
        </acteurs>
        <scenario></scenario>
    </film>
    <film>
        <titre>My Hero Academia</titre>
        <visa>568 789</visa>
        <nationalite>Japonais</nationalite>
        <pays>
            <nom>Japon</nom>
        </pays>
        <genres>
            <genre>Animation</genre>
            <genre>Action</genre>
            <genre>Comedie</genre>
        </genres>
        <exploitation>
            <date_de_sortie>2019_01_22</date_de_sortie>
            <nombre_entrees>1 896 754</nombre_entrees>
            <nombre_salles>148</nombre_salles>
        </exploitation>
        <realisateur>Kenji Nagasaki</realisateur>
        <duree>
            <heures unite="h">1</heures>
            <minutes unite="mn">35</minutes>
        </duree>
        <scenario></scenario>
    </film>
    <film>
        <titre>Le Dernier Maitre de l"air</titre>
        <visa>147 589</visa>
        <nationalite>Americain</nationalite>
        <pays>
            <nom>Amerique</nom>
            <nom>Japon</nom>
        </pays>
        <genres>
            <genre>Aventure</genre>
            <genre>Action</genre>
            <genre>Famille</genre>
            <genre>Fantastique</genre>
        </genres>
        <exploitation>
            <date_de_sortie>2010_08_28</date_de_sortie>
            <nombre_entrees>2 358 698</nombre_entrees>
            <nombre_salles>285</nombre_salles>
        </exploitation>
        <realisateur>Night Shyamalan</realisateur>
        <duree>
            <heures unite="h">1</heures>
            <minutes unite="mn">43</minutes>
        </duree>
        <acteurs> 
            <acteur>Noah Ringer</acteur>
            <acteur>Nicola Peltz</acteur>
        </acteurs>
        <scenario></scenario>
    </film>    
</films>
```

Here are the errors that I got:

> Document root element "films", must match DOCTYPE root "filmographie".

and

> The content of element type "film" must match  "(titre,visa,nationalite,pays,genres,exploitation,realisateur,duree,acteurs,scenario)".

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your second `film` element does not contain an `<acteurs>` element according to the DTD.

So you have to possibilities:

1. Add an `<acteurs>` element with the appropriate sub-elements to the second `film` element.
2. Change you DTD to

   ```
   <!ELEMENT films (film)+>
   <!ELEMENT film (titre, visa, nationalite, pays, genres, exploitation,       
   realisateur, duree, acteurs?, scenario)>
   <!ELEMENT titre (#PCDATA)>
   <!ELEMENT visa (#PCDATA)>
   <!ELEMENT nationalite (#PCDATA)>
   <!ELEMENT pays (nom)*>
   <!ELEMENT nom (#PCDATA)>
   <!ELEMENT genres (genre)+>
   <!ELEMENT genre (#PCDATA)>
   <!ELEMENT exploitation (date_de_sortie, nombre_entrees, nombre_salles)>
   <!ELEMENT date_de_sortie (#PCDATA)>
   <!ELEMENT nombre_entrees (#PCDATA)>
   <!ELEMENT nombre_salles (#PCDATA)>
   <!ELEMENT realisateur (#PCDATA)>
   <!ELEMENT duree (heures, minutes)>
   <!ELEMENT heures (#PCDATA)>
   <!ELEMENT minutes (#PCDATA)>
   <!ELEMENT acteurs (acteur+)>
   <!ELEMENT acteur (#PCDATA)>
   <!ATTLIST heures unite CDATA 'h'>
   <!ATTLIST minutes unite CDATA 'mn' >
   <!ELEMENT scenario (#PCDATA) >
   ```

   This DTD modifies one thing: It does add the optional operator `?` to the`acteurs` element in the `film` declaration. So the new definition is

   ```
   <!ELEMENT film (titre, visa, nationalite, pays, genres, exploitation, realisateur, duree, acteurs?, scenario)>
   ```

That does fix your problem and the solution to your problem is essentially adding one character.